# Openshift cron execute servlet - Scheduled Job

Tags: java, servlets, cron, scheduled-tasks, openshift

I need to execute a task every 5 minutes on my server to update some datas on a db, i've found that on openshift i have the cron that executes some script every tot time. Is it possibile to make a script that makes a simple call to a servlet or to a java code to run this job?
I am quite new to server side programming so please speak easy!

Ps. I am using a  Tomcat 6 (Jboss EWS 1.0), mySQL 5.5 server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS I understand you, you need your application to run sth every XX minutes.
To calculate the start time I made a helper function "getStartTime" With that I can use the human readable time like "23:30" (attention, I am from german, so it is not for AM/PM, just change for your needs).

Helper Method:

```
private static long getStartTime(String startTime) {
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(startTime.split(":")[0]);
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(startTime.split(":")[1]); 
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date dateNow = cal.getTime();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if(cal.getTime().before(dateNow)) {
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1);
        return cal.getTime().getTime();
    } else {
        return cal.getTime().getTime();
    }
}
```

Now you can use the ScheduledExecutorService from Java. Example:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    long startClearRequests = getStartTime(DEFAULT_JOB_START_TIME) - System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And set your needs into the scheduleAtFiexed Rate:

```
    scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(clearRequests, startClearRequests, Math.round(DEFAULT_JOB_PERIOD_HOURS * 60 * 60 * 1000), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

For example I use:

```
    private static final int NUM_OF_THREADS = 2;
    private static final String DEFAULT_JOB_START_TIME = "23:30";
    private static final double DEFAULT_JOB_PERIOD_HOURS = 24;
```

As you see, you can change the number of threads (depends of what your application is doing), the start time (this is just needed for application start (when to start the job the first time). 
And also the period (every XX hour the job shall run ... I took hours, but you need ti insert milliseconds at the end, so for 5 minutes (you have to tak 5 * 60 *1000 miliseconds.

Greetings

EDIT in respect to the athors comments:
To start things on application start, you have several methods. One method is to start a servlet on startup like this. Insert into the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletStartups</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>model.initialization.ServletStartups</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

This will call the Class ServletStartups on Application start (the number in load-on-startup is the priority, because you can have multiple entries and can decide which to start first (1, 2, 3 ...)

Now within your servlet you defines an init() method, which is automatically called, like that:

```
public class ServletStartups extends HttpServlet{


public void init() throws ServletException{
    // HEre you can put your methods as described above      //(scheduledExecutorService( ...   

}
```

}

IMPORTANT NOTE:
above I had a method "clearRequests", sorry this was my method, I have not renamed it to add it here. THis method will be called in my application every 24 hours.

the methods you call from the ScheduledExecutorService have to be a callable, like this:

```
private Runnable clearRequests = new Runnable() { 

    public void run() {
        try {
             // Here do your task
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my problem is that i don't know where and how to call this code, i've made a try with TimerTask but how can i say to my server to start this automatically?